# Why are these weight 3/2 Forms Eigenforms for the $T(p^2)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

In this proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kv2t.png) in the paper by Tunnell on Congruent Numbers, how does one conclude that

- the span of the weight $\frac{3}{2}$ forms $g\theta_2$ and $g\theta_8$ for $\Gamma_0(128)$ are $T(p^2)$ stable? i think there are some facts I need about half weight modular forms and how the $T(p^2)$ act on them to see this, for instance, it is mentioned in Koblitz's book on modular forms that the space of cusp forms of weight half-integer weight $k/2$ for $\Gamma_0(N)$ have a basis of eigenforms for Hecke operators $T(p^2)$ for all primes $p$ except maybe the primes dividing $N$. it is probably also relevant that it is mentioned earlier that the the three forms $g\theta_2, g\theta_8$ and $g\theta_{32}$ form a basis for the weight 3/2 forms for $\Gamma_0(128)$.
- $g(\theta_2 - \theta_8)$ and $g\theta_8$ are eigenforms for all the $T(p^2)$? I follow the work on exponents modulo 8 before this claim, but I don't see how this is conclude from that.
  here, $g$ is the modular form corresponding to the elliptic curve $E_1: y^2 = x^3 - x$, with a $q$ expansion of the form $g(z) = \sum (-1)^m q^{(4n+1)^2+8m^2}$. Also, $\theta_2 = \sum q^{2n^2}, \theta_8 = \sum q^{8n^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Hecke operators $T(p^2)$ act on the space of weight $3/2$ cusp forms of fixed level $N$ and trivial character, and this space is generated, for $N=128$, by $g\theta_2$, $g\theta_8$ and $g\theta_{32}$ (allegedly).

Furthermore, it is known that the above space contains a basis of cusp forms that are eigenfunctions for every $T(p^2)$ where $p\nmid N$ (we’ll call them the *good* Hecke operators).

What Tunnell does (if I understood well) is show (I would guess he’s using the direct $q$-expansion of Hecke operators, but you should check this actually exists in half-integer weight) that $f_1=g\theta_2, f_2=g\theta_8$ and $f_3=g(2\theta_{32}-\theta_8)$ are eigenfunctions for $T(3^2)$ and $T(5^2)$.

Now, $f_1$ and $f_2$ have (allegedly) the same eigenvalues for these specific operators, which are distinct from the eigenvalues of $f_3$. Because the good Hecke operators are self-adjoint and pairwise commute, this means that any linear combination of good Hecke operators applied to $f_1$ and $f_2$ also has the same eigenvalues for $T(3^2),T(5^2)$, and is therefore orthogonal to $f_3$.

So, if $S$ is the subspace generated by $f_1,f_2$ and $T$ the subspace generated by the images under the good Hecke operators of $f_1,f_2$, then $S \subset T \subset f_3^{\perp}$. Since $\dim{S}=2=\dim{f_3^{\perp}}$, $S=T=f_3^{\perp}$ and $S$ is stable under the good Hecke operators.

Since the good Hecke operators are self-adjoint, they also preserve $\mathbb{C}f_3$, and thus $f_3$ is an eigenform.

Then Tunnell discusses the basis $(f_1-f_2,f_2)$ of the space $S$. Let $A$ be a good Hecke operator: $A(f_1-f_2)=a(f_1-f_2)+bf_2$ for scalars $a,b$, by the above.

Let $n$ be any integer such that the coefficient $\lambda$ of degree $n$ of the $q$-expansion of $f_2$ is nonzero. Then $n \equiv 1\pmod{8}$, so the coefficient of degree $n$ of the $q$-expansion of $f_1-f_2$ vanishes. Therefore, the coefficient of degree $n$ of the $q$-expansion of $A(f_1-f_2)$ is $b\lambda$. But, by the explicit formulas, since $n \not\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, the coefficient of degree $n$ of the $q$-expansion of $A(f_1-f_2)$ must vanish.

Therefore, $b=0$, and $A(f_1-f_2)$ is proportional to $f_1-f_2$; hence $f_1-f_2$ is an eigenform. One proves in the same way that $f_2$ is an eigenform.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify some basic steps (I am beginner :P), since $T(p^2)$ preserves the space (of modular forms with weight $3 / 2$, level $128$ and trivial character, spanned by $\{g\theta_2, g\theta_8, g\theta_{32}\}$, as proven in [Serre-Stark, 1976](http://cm2vivi2002.free.fr/JPS-biblio/JPS-25.pdf), theorem B), we just have to compute the image of the basis under the operator $T(3^2)$ and $T(5^2)$, maybe just the first 3 (or 4) non-zero coefficients, then solve for the basis and diagonalise it for a eigenbasis (just like linear algebra)?

Comment: That’s certainly an efficient way to compute it. But the “problem” is that $g\theta_2$ and $g\theta_8$ have the same eigenvalues, so you can’t say only with $T(3^2)$ and $T(5^2)$ which linear combination of the two is the eigenform for *all* the $T(p^2)$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you mind looking at my most recent question, also on modular forms? It might not be exactly your expertise but maybe you have some ideas

Comment: thank you. as a follow up, does anyone have any advice on how to actually check that $f_1$ say is an eigenform under $T(3^2)$ and $T(5^2)$? it seems difficult to verify it using only the formula for the $q$-expansion. i thought of writing $g\theta_2 = \sum a_nq^n$, and use a nice formula for $a_n$ found in the paper or other sources. for exmaple, one can prove $a_n$ is $ \# \{ (x,y,z) : n = 2x^2 + y^2 + 8z^2,\, 2 \mid z \} - \#\{ (x,y,z) : n = 2x^2 + y^2 + 8z^2, \, 2 \nmid z \}$. but this isnt getting me far.

Comment: on another note, it is claimed in the beginning of Tunnell's proof that $f_1$(in your notation) is an eigenform for all the good Hecke operators. but then we are proving $f_1 - f_2$ is an Eigenform, not $f_1$. To prove that $f_1$ is an eigenform, I think we can just do the same thing but with $f_2 - f_1$ instead of $f_1-f_2$ ?